# Complex Analysis curve

Tags: complex-analysis

We are given three complex numbers a,b,and c. Consider $Re(az^{2} + bz +c)=0$. What is this curve? I am having a hard time approaching this problem. Any suggestions or help would be great.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60801).

Answer (score 1):

If $a=a_1+ia_2$, $b=b_1+ib_2$, $c=c_1+ic_2$ and $z=x+iy$, then $$z^2=x^2-y^2+2ixy$$ hence
$az^2+bz+c$ equals
$$
a_1(x^2-y^2)-2a_2xy+b_1x-b_2y+c_1+i\cdot(\text{something real}),
$$
and you are done.